# Car engine races up when stop

Tags: manual-transmission, suzuki, alto

my car is a manual transmission one. When i speed the car and slow down it by releasing the gas padel, the engine races continously.Even when i stop the car the engine races. is it normal? Recently i did an engine tune up, but no change. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You could help us by giving us the year/make/model/engine of the car. Then, please let us know if there are any check engine light codes which you've read?

Comment: It is 2010 indian alto manual transmission. There is no check engine light codes.

Comment: When you did this "tune up" did you make sure the idle speed etc was correct **before** starting, and made sure all linkages were free and operating correctly?

Comment: yeah they said no problem in that area. but i can notice the racing issue.i dont have much knowledge of automobile area though. this happens in the morning when i start the car and when speeding and slow down in the traffic.